# windows 7 taskbar pin custom shortcuts to jumplist

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

For example I have TightVNC Viewer pinned to taskbar, it does not allow a jumplist (pinning multiple items or storing recent items). However I have a couple of shortcuts to vncviewer.exe that take arguments. Is there a way to get these in a jumplist for the vncviewer taskbar icon anyway?

Found [jumplist launcher](http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher) already, but it's not exactly what I'm after + it's buggy (cannot add arguments to the exe)

Comment: See if this is any help...http://windows7center.com/tutorials/how-to-pin-any-item-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/

Comment: no that's for pinning anything to taskbar - I have n problem pinngn vncviewer.exe to the taskbar, I want to add shortcuts to the jumplist (edited question for clarity)

Comment: Is it buggy or just lacking a feature you want? Sounds like the latter.

Comment: no it's buggy: I add a parameter, the gui supports it, and it doesn't work as expected (ie doesn't work at all and gives an error). That's what I call a bug. And I've been programming long enough to know what a bug is. See my comment here: http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/#comment-129415043

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so JumplistLauncher does what I want, but it doesn't allow me to enter arguments for vncviewer.
However I found msdn's [Jump List Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940352(v=vs.85).aspx) on which I assume JumplistLauncher is based. I modified the code and made an app that reads a simple settings file in which I specify tasks (== exe path, arguments, title and icon) for the jumplist. This is basically everything JumplistLauncher does, but without the gui, and it does work with arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind that this is way late, but [Jumplist Extender](http://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender) sounds like it does what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks nonetheless!! I'm glad I can see somebody else's code as well o see how they solved certain problems.

Comment: Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

Answer (score 0):

See [Jumplist Launcher Lets You Create Custom Jump Lists in Windows 7](http://www.guidingtech.com/2624/jumplist-launcher-custom-jumplists-windows-7/) :

> If you want to go a step further and
>   create a custom jump list then you’ll
>   have to use a third-party tool called
>   the Jumplist Launcher. You can add up
>   to 60 programs, files or folders to
>   the program interface and pin it to
>   the taskbar using this tool.

It can create this kind of jumplists :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate method to pin just about anything, not sure if an argument could be incorporated or not.

http://windows7center.com/tutorials/how-to-pin-any-item-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/

.

Comment: it's not what I'm after: I want to set any item in the jumplist, so after something is pinned already..