# Where does Jumplist store its data and how can I edit it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, jumplist

They are grossly unreliable on their own and I'd really like to have a little more control.

[I found out where explorer store its taskbar jumplist.](https://superuser.com/questions/148073/windows-explorer-jumplist-delay) But the files in there appears to be binary data. Is there a way I can edit these?

[I also found that 3rd party programs do the job](https://superuser.com/questions/233554/windows-7-taskbar-pin-custom-shortcuts-to-jumplist) but I'm reluctant to use them unless there's absolutely no way I can tweak the built-in functionality.

[image: scr] [image]